# GeoServer REST missing datastores

Tags: geoserver, rest

When I query GeoServer at

```html
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/mike/datastores.xml
```

I get no results, but I definitely have a data store under mike/.

Moreover, the stock geoserver installation came with a workspace called "nurc" with 4 datastores and none of them are listed either. What's the deal?

Viewing isn't a big issue, but when I go to delete a store via rest, it can't seem to find it. Again, the datastore is clearly there per the Geoserver web GUI.

Comment: do you have tomcat installed? likely it is a redirection/config setup issue.

Comment: Nah, i'm using the web server packaged with geoserver (jetty?). sorry, i should have mentioned some workspaces (topp) do return results so the  config looks ok.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to create a new Workspace from the GeoServer web console then immediately see it at: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/

I would not try to access datastores.xml directly.

Answer (score 0):

The default `nurc` workspace doesn't contain any `datastores` (vector datasets) but it does contain 4 `coveragestores` (raster datasets) so the following responses are expected.

```
curl -u admin:geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/nurc/datastores.xml" 

<dataStores/>

curl -u admin:geoserver "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/nurc/coveragestores.xml"
<coverageStores>
  <coverageStore>
    <name>arcGridSample</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/nurc/coveragestores/arcGridSample.xml" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  </coverageStore>
  <coverageStore>
    <name>img_sample2</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/nurc/coveragestores/img_sample2.xml" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  </coverageStore>
  <coverageStore>
    <name>mosaic</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/nurc/coveragestores/mosaic.xml" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  </coverageStore>
  <coverageStore>
    <name>worldImageSample</name>
    <atom:link xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" rel="alternate" href="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/nurc/coveragestores/worldImageSample.xml" type="application/atom+xml"/>
  </coverageStore>
</coverageStores>
```